# keysym Control_R = Left; Does not repeat when held

Tags: keyboard

```
keysym Control_R = Left
```

My right ctrl key switches back to right ctrl if I hold it, rather than acting as if I'm holding the left arrow key. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
remove Control = Control_R
```

Filler text because my answer was too short.